# Zoom on UIView contained in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have some trouble handling zoom on UIScrollView that contains many subviews. I already saw many answers on SO, but none of them helped me.

So, basically what I'm doing is simple : I have a class called UIFreeView :

```
import UIKit
```

class UIFreeView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
var mainUIView: UIView!

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var arrayOfView: [UIView]?


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

fileprivate func setupView() {
    // MainUiView
    self.mainUIView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
    self.addSubview(mainUIView)

    // ScrollView
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.frame)
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.addSubview(self.scrollView)
}

func reloadViews(postArray:[Post]?) {
    if let postArray = postArray {
        print("UIFreeView::reloadVIew.postArraySize = \(postArray.count)")
        let size: CGFloat = 80.0
        let margin: CGFloat = 20.0
        scrollView.contentSize.width = (size * CGFloat(postArray.count))+(margin*CGFloat(postArray.count))
        scrollView.contentSize.height = (size * CGFloat(postArray.count))+(margin*CGFloat(postArray.count))

        for item in postArray {
            let view = buildPostView(item)

            self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

}

fileprivate func buildPostView(_ item:Post) -> UIView {
    // Const
    let size: CGFloat = 80.0
    let margin: CGFloat = 5.0

    // Var
    let view = UIView()
    let textView = UITextView()
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()
    // Setup view

    let x = CGFloat(UInt64.random(lower: UInt64(0), upper: UInt64(self.scrollView.contentSize.width)))
    let y = CGFloat(UInt64.random(lower: UInt64(0), upper: UInt64(self.scrollView.contentSize.height)))


    view.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                        y: y,
                        width: size,
                        height: size)

    // Setup background view
    backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: 0,
                                       width: view.frame.size.width,
                                       height: view.frame.size.height)
    var bgName = ""
    if (item.isFromCurrentUser) {
        bgName = "post-it-orange"
    } else {
        bgName = "post-it-white"
    }
    backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: bgName)
    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

    // Setup text view 
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: margin,
                            y: margin,
                            width: view.frame.size.width - margin*2,
                            height: view.frame.size.height - margin*2)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.text = item.content
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    view.addSubview(textView)

    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    return view
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.scrollView
}

func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.scrollView)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.scrollView)
    }
}

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
```

}

This class is working perfectly, I can scroll through all my views, but I can't zoom-in and zoom-out in order to see less/more views on my screen.

I think the solution is simple, but I can't seem to find a real solution for my problem ..

Thanks !

Comment: You are saying that you have looked through other answers and not found any solution, **even with that said**, you havnt even implemented https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619409-scrollviewdidzoom?language=objc , I can do a simple search and find many simliar duplicates. https://www.google.se/search?dcr=0&q=uiview+inside+uiscrollview+zoom+stackoverflow&oq=uiview+inside+uiscrollview+zoom+stackoverflow Did none of these answers help you?

Comment: I tried to add a mainView with all subviews contained in this mainView and add this mainView to the scrollView, but after that the scroll did not work anymore.

Comment: You need to provide minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale to your scrollView. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619428-minimumzoomscale , and implement the delegate method I linked above, and calculate the new frameSize depending on the **scrollView.zoomScale** that is called in the delegate method, after you calculate it correctly, you update the UIView frame in the delegate method accordingly. A more elaborated answer in code can be found if you look through the other answers I linked above. I am to tired to write for u :P